# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a react app, but i am facing this error-> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')". how to fix this?
my code is:

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid, CircularProgress } from "@material-ui/core";
import Post from "./Post/Post";
import useStyles from "./styles";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const Posts = () => {
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.Posts);
  const classes = useStyles();

  console.log(posts);
  return (!posts.length ? <CircularProgress/> :(
   <Grid className={classes.container} container alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
      {
        posts.map((post)=> (
              <Grid key={post._id} item xs={12} sm={6}>
                <Post post = {post} />
              </Grid>
        ))
      }

   </Grid>
 )
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says the type of *posts* is Undefined. As you are getting that value from *Posts* in state object, that means that *Posts* is not initialized in your state.
Try initializing "Posts" with empty Array`([])` in your initial state object.

Answer (score 0):

use `!post || !post.length` or `!posts?.length`

Comment: ```!post || !post.length``` works. but i can not see my posts from mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this , `!posts?.length > -1 ?`. As you are checking if the post array is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

try `posts && <Grid>`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.